# How to create a script whith saves a file with spaces in ZSH

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm trying to use the following script in my zsh shell (I found that code [here](https://github.com/bevacqua/dotfiles/blob/0ba35a82c9d876a92e9841f96f6a2d5da5e345c1/zsh/aliases#L4-L10)):

```
# some todo.sh file
IFS_OLD="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
touch $(echo ~/Área\ de\ Trabalho/$@)
IFS="$IFS_OLD"
```

The problem is, when I run this script using zsh, like `todo.sh alimentar o cachorro`, the file is saved with the name *alime tar o cachorro*, but it works fine in bash. I know it may be a silly error, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Why I need it? My desktop is my todo list, it has only that - empty files whose title is the description of the task. It works best for me because my desktop is **always** clean, it only has my tasks. For example:

```
$ ls ~/Área\ de\ Trabalho/
# nothing, all tasks done

$ todo comprar leite
$ ls ~/Área\ de\ Trabalho/
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsmagalhaes lsmagalhaes 0 Fev  5 20:28 comprar leite

$ todo comprar arroz
$ ls ~/Área\ de\ Trabalho/
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsmagalhaes lsmagalhaes 0 Fev  5 20:28 comprar leite
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsmagalhaes lsmagalhaes 0 Fev  5 20:29 comprar arroz

$ todo alimentar o cachorro
$ ls ~/Área\ de\ Trabalho/
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsmagalhaes lsmagalhaes 0 Fev  5 20:28 comprar leite
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsmagalhaes lsmagalhaes 0 Fev  5 20:29 comprar arroz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsmagalhaes lsmagalhaes 0 Fev  5 20:30 alime tar o cachorro  # BUG!
```

Simply put, the command should save a file with name `alimentar o cachorro`, but instead it saves `alime tar o cachorro`.

Comment: `touch` is supposed to create an empty file. Please consider adding details of `/bin/ls -l '/Area\ de\ Trablho/'*` AND an example of what you do need to show us what is not working. Its not clear (to me) from your description. Good luck.

Comment: Clarified, what do you think?

Comment: +1, a hundred times better. now I understand your problem, but its still slightly a mystery. Is the problem that there is a space now `alime tar o cachorro` when you didn't include a space there? What happens if you execute `touch "~/Área\ de\ Trabalho/alimentar o cachorro"` from the command line? Same problem? If so, then bug, or something I don't understand about language processing. If it is OK, then that points to a problem in the script. Still possibly a bug. Good luck.

Comment: oh, right, I don't see that you really need the `$(echo ...)`. Just do `touch` as I show above, replacing 'fileName' with "${@}". Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter, both your and Glenn' answers worked well, for me =D

Comment: Glad to help. Just remember to illustrate your problems as you have done above, so all you need is "1. I have this data (or situation), 2. I want to change it to look like this. 3. my code is this, 4. it is giving me this output. 5. what do I need to change" Good luck and keep posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `IFS=$'\n'` is bash syntax: [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting). I don't know zsh, but it seems zsh is handling that just like `IFS=n` which is probably why `alimentar` turns into `alime tar`

Perhaps you just want:

```
IFS="
"
```

with just a newline between the quotes.

But probably you just want to ignore IFS and use

```
touch ~/"Área de Trabalho/$*"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) (and simplify). This should work in pretty much any shell:

```
touch ~/"Área de Trabalho/$1"
```

The original code is ... not optimal. [What are you trying to accomplish?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: I use my own desktop as a todo list, so every time I need to remember something, I call guake, type "todo comprar leite amanhã" and that's it.